# Don't allow to select past date and time in jquery-simple-datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I have used jquery-simple-datetimepicker

available here

```
https://github.com/mugifly/jquery-simple-datetimepicker
```

my code is

```
<input name="day_time" id="day_time_input" type="text" value="" />

 jQuery(function () {
         jQuery('#day_time_input').appendDtpicker();
 });
```

now want to prevent user from selecting past dates.

so how do to that?

[image]

Comment: Can you try if `$("#day_time_input").datepicker({ minDate: 0 })` works

Comment: I have used another plugin for this, so .datepicker will dont work,its date time picker

Answer (score 1):

Try : `datepicker` is your element `ID`

```
$("#day_time_input").datetimepicker({
   minDate: 0 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){   
            $('*[name=date1]').appendDtpicker({
                "closeOnSelected": true,
                "futureOnly": true
            });
        });         
    </script>
```

use futureOnly

Answer (score 1):

in the file jquery.simple-dtpicker.js

find

```
 var getDefaults = function() {
       return {
        "current": null,
        "dateFormat": "default",
        "locale": "en",
        "animation": true,
        "minuteInterval": 30,
        "firstDayOfWeek": 0,
        "closeOnSelected": false,
        "timelistScroll": true,
        "calendarMouseScroll": true,
        "todayButton": true,
        "dateOnly": false,
        "futureOnly": false,
        "minDate" : null,
        "maxDate" : null,
        "autodateOnStart": true,
        "minTime":"00:00",
        "maxTime":"23:59",
        "onShow": null,
        "onHide": null
    };
};
```

and change

```
 "futureOnly": true
```

from false to true.

Answer (score 1):

you want to add *futureOnly: true*

```
$("#div").appendDtpicker({
    futureOnly: true
});
```